# BigQuery querying , update field on a condition based on a group by count

Tags: google-bigquery, data-cleaning

The query I would like to perform in BigQuery has as goal that based on a certain value from a group by count, that I want to have a certain value overwritten.

my current query

```
UPDATE MAN_18.MAN_4y
SET actual_related_customer = customer_code
WHERE (SELECT IF(arc_count > 1,1,0) AS double_cust FROM (SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT(actual_related_customer)) AS arc_count
FROM MAN_18.MAN_4y
GROUP BY customer_code)
WHERE double_cust = 1)
```

The desired result looks as follows :

From the table MAN_4y, I want to use the columns customer_code & actual_related_customer to perform actions on. First, I want to know if a customer_code can have more than 1 distinct actual_related_customer. If so, which in this case means arc_count is larger than 1, I want to use the set of the customer_code (s) to look within the MAN_4y table. I want to look at the actual_related_customer values for these customer_code (s). If a row for one of these customer_code (s) has an actual_related_customer that is not the same as the customer_code value, I want to overwrite it with the present customer_code value. You could also interpret this that for all values of customer_code for which the customer_code has an arc_count > 1, then write that customer_code value to actual_related_customer.

Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: What's the question here. You can have an update like this, but you need first to run the select and write into a new table, then join that table in the update and run it.

Comment: @Pentium10 has to be done in 2 steps no matter what then?

Comment: yes as you can't update the table from data that is coming from the same table

Comment: @Pentium10, if you think this is the answer, might you post it as an answer in order to let the question owner to accept it and help the community to distinct good answers?

Comment: was waiting for additional feedback

Answer (score 3):

Below is how I would do this in a simple **one step**  (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `project.MAN_18.MAN_4y`
SET actual_related_customer = customer_code
WHERE customer_code IN (
  SELECT customer_code
  FROM `project.MAN_18.MAN_4y`
  GROUP BY customer_code
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT actual_related_customer) > 1
)
```

As an extremely simplified example:

if original table looks like below:

```
Row     customer_code   actual_related_customer  
1       1               3    
2       1               4    
3       2               5
```

then after UPDATE is applied - table is updated to

```
Row     customer_code   actual_related_customer  
1       1               1    
2       1               1    
3       2               5
```

Unless I have read question wrongly  - this is exactly what is expected

Comment: to me this retrieves:
Error: DML over table 'project.test.table' is not supported.

Comment: It worked, sorry. It was my fault, I used a table linked to a Google Sheet. Thank you very much Mikhail :)

Comment: sure, no problem :o)

Answer (score 1):

The action you tried to build is possible in BQ.

What you need to do is to write the subselect to a destination table, and in the UPDATE statement you reference the destionation table as DB engines don't offer a way to reference the same table in the subquery.

This results two steps.